# sql case in column and where section without repeating the case

Tags: sql

I have a sql statement like this but with a very long case expression in it and I need it in the where as well as in the column. Is there a way to use the case without repeating it in the column and where section.

```
select * from c.name, (case when c.age = 1 then 0 when c.age = 2 then 1 ... etc else -1 end;)
from customer c 
where (case when c.age = 1 then 0 when c.age = 2 then 1 ... etc else -1 end;) > 0
```

Comment: Could you redefine your statement as CASE (c.age > 0) THEN c.age - 1 ELSE -1 END ? You could use a CTE or similar but it seems heavy for what you are doing if the condition is no more complicated than that.

Comment: Can't you just use `c.age - 1`?

Comment: it is a more complicated select statement then the example. So I have to use the case

Comment: Also: What is your exact SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: it is postgres. but the sql sould work with other databases as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would use a subquery to get around this problem:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT c.name,
           CASE WHEN c.age = 1 THEN 0 WHEN c.age = 2 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END AS val
    FROM customer c
    INNER JOIN employee e ON c.emp_id = e.id
) t
WHERE val > 0;
```

But in practice if you had a list of age values which get mapped to positive values, you could just use a single level query with a `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT c.name,
       CASE WHEN c.age = 1 THEN 0 WHEN c.age = 2 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END AS val
FROM customer c
WHERE age IN (2, ...);
```

Comment: ok, but when I have joins in it like
```
select * from c.name, (case when c.age = 1 then 0 when c.age = 2 then 1 ... etc else -1 end;)
from customer c
inner join employee e 
where e.age> 20
and (case when c.age = 1 then 0 when c.age = 2 then 1 ... etc else -1 end;) > 0

how to use the subselect then?

Comment: Nothing changes, just wrap your join query in a subquery and then check the alias.

Comment: sorry I don't get it. could you give me an example with a join?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of consolidating would be to use a *lateral join*

```
select * 
from customer c,
lateral (values(case when c.age = 1 then 0 when c.age = 2 then 1 ... etc else -1 end))v(AgeCheck)
where AgeCheck > 0;
```